How to remove warning about "git auth provider"
I am currently working in VS Code. I write some code, run it, the terminal shows the output, everything is fine. I close VS Code. Now whenever I open VS Code, the output (same output which I ran last time, before closing VS Code) in the terminal has a warning sign. If run the same program again, it creates another section and runs the program. There is no problem while running any program or anything, but that warning sign irritates me. How to remove it?
This is what is shown when I hover over the warning sign:


I think the message with the ! symbol is the warning, not the one you have marked in red.

Ohh, i just noticed it, thanks. Btw they both require the same thing. Can i do something about it? Its very annoying. I have to always relaunch terminal or it itself creates a new one.

If you don't actually use VS Code's Git functionality, one way to get rid of this warning is to disable the built-in Git extension.
In the Extensions pane, filter by @builtin and then look for Git.  Go into its settings and then at the top of the settings window search @ext:vscode git.enabled.  Uncheck the option and then relaunch VS Code.  You should no longer see the warning.
If you do use the Git function in VS Code, I haven't found any solution to remove the warning without disabling the extension.
